# Conditional statement works in development but not production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

Update: Paulo in the comments below nailed it. I was not signed in on production, so 'count' resulted in an undefined variable, breaking the conditional.

***(StackExchange is not totally working right now, so I can't post comments, but if you read this thanks!)***

I have this weird issue: a conditional statement I wrote for the 'title' element in my application view works in development, but not in production.

Here's what it looks like:

```
<!-- count unread notifications -->
 <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <% count  = 0 %>
   <% current_user.notifications.each do |notification| %>
     <% if notification.state == 0 %>
       <% count+= 1 %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>

<title>Noises <%= count != 0 ? '(' + (count).to_s + ')' : ' ';  %></title>
```

What it's meant to do it produce something that looks like this, when notifications where state == 0 are present:

"Noises (x)" - where x is the number of unread (state is 0) notification

and when no unread notifications are present:

"Noises".

This works in development, but in production, users with no unread notifications still see parentheses, like this:

Noises ()

Does anyone have an idea why this happen?

Comment: I only see on reason for that, user_signed_in? returns false.

Comment: I agree with Paulo.  What happens when you put <%= user_signed_in %> to a div in your view.  Does it show false?